# make window "always on top" - on boot?

Tags: command-line, desktop, openbox, window-management

I use **openbox window manager**.
to keep a window always on top...
I right click on the title bar and select

```
 Layer ---> Always On Top
```

is there a way to do this via command line ?

Reason I am asking is.. I need to automatically do it on boot.
(when desktop loads )

Comment: This is done by the X Windowing system.  I'm sure there is a little application somewhere but if you want to cut/paste/compile your own which will put your application on top, here's a link -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20733215/how-to-make-a-window-always-on-top

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to assign per-application settings with openbox as detailed in http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:Applications. There's also some good documentation about it in the default system-wide configuration file `/etc/xdg/openbox/rc.xml`.

Look for the `<applications>` section in `~/.config/openbox/rc.xml`

```
<applications>
    ...
    <application name="EXAMPLE">
        <layer>above</layer>
    </application>
    ...
</applications>
```

You can use `xprop` to find the NAME or CLASS of your window.